Is there method to map physical memory to virtual memory in Windows user mode?
Of course I know how to map physical memory to virtual memory in driver.
And I want to know if there method to performance it without a driver.
Or may I map physical memory to multiple virtual address?
Thanks

The whole point of user mode is to hide details like memory mapping from you.  Being able to do what you request would be a huge security hole.

what is the sense/target of this ?
